# конфигурационные переменные доступные для любого JavaBean или POJO в ear

Tags: java, ejb, websphere

Доброе время суток.

Я столкнулся со следующей проблемой: есть базовый абстрактный класс в котором определено некоторое поле и метод учитывающий это поле. Есть два JavaBean, которые являются потомками этого абстрактного класса. Эти классы реализуют один и тот же интерфейс. В родительском классе определены поле и метод общие для всех потомков.

Вопрос как ПРАВИЛЬНО передавать конфигурационную переменную в родительский класс?

Вместо web.xml, в котором можно было бы определить переменную окружения у меня толкько ejb-jar.xml, но в нем можно указать переменные окружения только для конкретного JavaBean, в application.xml указанные переменные окружения не доступны для contextLookup из любого класса.

Хотелось бы каким-то "автомагическим" методом "воткнуть" общую для всех дочерних классов переменную в родительский класс, причем саму переменную определять в настройках развернутого приложения на сервере приложений. В качестве AS используется WAS 8.5

Answer (score 1):

Предполагаю, что зависеть будет от того какую именно переменную вы хотите завести. Но есть способ использовать [websphere environment variables](http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSAW57_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.nd.iseries.doc/ae/tcws_variable.html). Также использовать [custom properties](https://wiki.base22.com/plugins/servlet/mobile?contentId=63504409#content/view/63504409) (подробно объяснено со скриншотами).

Comment: Пожалуйста, постарайтесь публиковать развернутые ответы содержащие конкретный пример минимального решения, дополняя их ссылкой на источник. Ответы–ссылки (как и комментарии) не добавляют знаний в Рунет.

Comment: @a.chugunov  custom properties вроде бы подходит под задачу, но тогда как быть, если AS будет не WAS а JBOSS например?